# Delphi xe8 Multi-Device Json post

Tags: php, json, delphi-xe8

Bom pessoal eu gostaria de enviar uns dados por json para um servidor php apartir do Delphi, Eu tentei fazer desta forma:

Delphi Cliente:

```
procedure TForm7.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  code       : Integer;
  sResponse  : String;
  Json       : String;
  JsonToSend : TStringStream;
begin
  Json       := '{"email" : "teste@teste.com.br", "password" : "123testar"}';
  JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create( UTF8Encode(Json) );
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.Method               := 'POST';
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType       := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';

    try
      sResponse := IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/webservice/receber.php', JsonToSend);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    Memo1.lines.clear;
    Memo1.lines.add(sResponse);
  finally
    JsonToSend.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Servidor PHP:

```
<?php
$jason_data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/webservice/receber.php');
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_data);
print_r($decoded_data);
?>
```

Mas não obtive sucesso, Alguém saberia como fazer isso funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Bom como nenhum de vocês deram importância/atenção para a minha pergunta então eu pesquisei o dobro e consegui resolver o meu problema.
O código abaixo mostra como enviar valores através do Indy POST para uma pagina:

```
 var
Parameters : TStringList;
Begin
  Parameters := TStringList.Create;
  Parameters.Add('nome=lucas');
  Memo1.Text:= IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/webservice/receber.php',Parameters);
End;
```

E no PHP de recebimentos podemos receber o valor desta forma:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
echo $_POST['nome'];
}
?>
```

Postei aí para facilitar a quem está com o mesmo problema ou dificuldade.
Lembrando que se vocês quiserem enviar por json dai é só modificar e colocar para enviar por Json, Mas essa aí já é a base. Espero que tenha ajudado.